# Search Engine Friendly links not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Only thing that works is www.foo.com and foo.com (basically the index.php)

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [r=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar.com/public_html/$1

RewriteRule review(s?)(\/?)$ /bar.com/public_html/reviews.php
RewriteRule products(\/?)$ /bar.com/public_html/products.php
```

Some addresses will work if I remove the trailing slash, others give me a 404 with or without a trailing slash.

Comment: SOLVED: I solved it by taking the page rewrite rules (the *.php) and placing them in the .htaccess file of the bar.com/public_html/ directory.